# MailKit email Attachment for .NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, optimization, email-attachments, smtpclient, mailkit

**My problem:** 
I want to create a csv file from my ever-changing classes and data and email that as an attachment.

**The good:**
I can create a csv file using the following code.

```
private IEnumerable<string> ToCsv<T>(string separator, IEnumerable<T> objectlist)
        {
            FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(T).GetFields();
            PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
            yield return String.Join(separator, fields.Select(f => f.Name).Union(properties.Select(p => p.Name)).ToArray());
            foreach (var o in objectlist)
            {
                yield return string.Join(separator, (properties.Select(p => (p.GetValue(o, null) ?? "").ToString())).ToArray());
            }
        }
```

and use it by

```
    using (TextWriter tw = File.CreateText("filepath" + "filename"))
    {
        foreach (var line in ToCsv(",", data))
        {
            tw.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
```

**The bad:**

```
                string FromAddress = "myaddress@gmail.com";
                string FromAdressTitle = "Email Title";
                string ToAddress = "someaddress@domain.com";
                string ToAdressTitle = "To address Title";
                string Subject = "RE: some subject line";

                //Smtp Server
                string SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
                //Smtp Port Number
                int SmtpPortNumber = 587;

                var mimeMessage = new MimeMessage();
                mimeMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(FromAdressTitle, FromAddress));
                mimeMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(ToAdressTitle, ToAddress));
                mimeMessage.Subject = Subject;

                var builder = new BodyBuilder();
                builder.Attachments.Add(@"filepath");
                mimeMessage.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();

                using (var client = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    client.Connect(SmtpServer, SmtpPortNumber, false);
                    client.Authenticate("username", "password");
                    client.Send(mimeMessage);
                    client.Disconnect(true);
                }
```

**This works fine but I dont want to create a file but create an attachment from memory stream instead. Is it possible?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the BodyBuilder class to construct the list of attachments.

The MimeMessage.Attachments property has always been an IEnumerable, so it was never possible to add attachments in that way.

Comment: I was able to get that part working. But now I need to optimize. I have updated the question. Please take a look.

Comment: BodyBuilder.Attachments.Add() has an overload that takes a Stream, so yes. In that override, the `fileName` parameter is just used to set the filename property.